# Reverse mapping

Tags: solidity, testnets, mapping

Can i do reverse mapping in solidity language.

for example:

case 1 :
`mapping(address=>uint256)`   ----- mapping

case 2:
`mapping(uint256=>address)` ------reverse mapping

can we perform case 2 in solidity successfully?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `mapping(uint256=>address)` is valid.

> Mapping types are declared as mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType). Here
>   _KeyType can be almost any type except for a mapping, a dynamically sized array, a contract, an enum and a struct. _ValueType can actually
>   be any type, including mappings.

But, if the value of the first mapping is a mapping or struct, then a reverse mapping would not be possible.

See the [source (Solidity docs)](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings) for more information.